# How to pass success function name as a function parameter to AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here I am trying to make AJAX call as a single function, for that I am passing success function name as a function parameter to the AJAX call function.

I tried writhing the following function:

```
function ApiCallFunction(Datatext, ApiName, FunctionName) {
  $.ajax({
    url: Apiurl + ApiName,
    type: "POST",
    data: Datatext,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      var funname = FunctionName + '("' + data + '")';
      eval(funname);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
      ErrorWhileSave(jsonValue.Message);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      ErrorWhileSave("");
    }
  });
}
```

Function call:

```
var datatext = {
  BillChild: {},
  BillDate: "2018-07-23T08:35:32.319Z",
  EntryTime: "2018-07-23T08:35:32.319Z",
  ExitTime: "2018-07-23T08:35:32.319Z",
  TotalTime: "2018-07-23T08:35:32.319Z",
  Total: 0,
  OtherCharges: 0,
  Discount: 0,
  TaxableAmount: 0,
  TotalTax: 0,
  GrandTotal: 0,
  RoundOff: 0,
  NetAmount: 0,
  ByCash: 0,
  ByBank: 0,
  CashReceived: 0,
  BalanceReceivable: 0,
  FirmId: 0,
  UserId: 0,
  BillId: 35,
  CustomerId: 0,
  BranchId: 0,
  BillType: "string",
  BillNo: "string",
  PaymentType: "string",
  Notes: "string",
  TaxType: "string",
  BankId: "string",
  CreatedBy: "string",
  HostIp: "string",
  BranchTransfer: "string",
  ConsultId: 0,
  SearchKey: "string",
  Flag: "SELECTONE"
};

var Datatext = (JSON.stringify(datatext));
ApiCallFunction(Datatext, "Bill_master", "ReturnFunction");
```

And the Success function am trying to use is:

```
function ReturnFunction(ReturnValue) {
  alert(data.data.Table1[0].BillId);
}
```

When I tried `alert(ReturnValue)` it showed as `object object`. I also tried `ReturnValue.data.data.Table1[0].BillId` still am not able to use the values. AJAX call is success and I am getting value in it, but I am unable to pass the result JSON object to other function.

How can I pass JSON object to other function? Please help me.

Comment: `success:FunctionName`.......?

Comment: You can pass the function directly by parameter, and call it in the ajax callback

Comment: @vikscool i tried that also !! `FunctionName` is now working as a variable !!

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways by which you can achieve what you are trying to do.

> **Method 1** simply assigning the function object as the parameters

```
function ApiCallFunction(Datatext, ApiName, onSucess,onError) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Apiurl + ApiName,
        type: "POST",
        data: Datatext,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSucess,
        error: onError,
        failure: function (response) {
            ErrorWhileSave("");
        }
    });
}
```

and have the implementation of the function as:

```
function ReturnFunction(response){
 //assuming that response is of JSON type
 alert(response.data.Table1[0].BillId);
}

function myError(response){
 console.log(JSON.parse(response.responseText).Message);
}
```

calling:

```
ApiCallFunction(DataText,"Bill_master",ReturnFunction,myError);
```

> **Method 2** if you happen to have a string instead of the function object

```
function ApiCallFunction(Datatext, ApiName, FunctionName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Apiurl + ApiName,
        type: "POST",
        data: Datatext,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             window[FunctionName].apply(this,data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
            ErrorWhileSave(jsonValue.Message);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            ErrorWhileSave("");
        }
    });
}
```

Calling:

```
ApiCallFunction(DataText,"Bill_master","ReturnFunction");
```

Comment: Additional checks may help prevent running into errors! 
typeof callback === "function" (function as a reference)
typeof window["callback"] === "function" (function name passed as a string)

Comment: @jeetaz yes that can be helpful.

Comment: `success: onSucess` is not working cz we need function name on `onSucess` variable.unfortunately its nor recognized as a variable in this format

Comment: @kirk is there any error and  have you tried calling it the way I mentioned.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` is the error am getting

Comment: @kirk what I have written in the function `ReturnFunction ` is by  assuming  that the response from the server is coming as a JSON object but if it is coming as a JSON string then please parse it by using `JSON.parse(response)` and assign it to a variable and access the properties and for more debugging try putting a breakpoint at the success function or simply do a `console.log(response )` to check what are you getting from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function address (callback):

```
function ApiCallFunction(Datatext, ApiName, FunctionName) {
        $.ajax({
            url: Apiurl + ApiName,
            type: "POST",
            data: Datatext,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                FunctionName(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                ErrorWhileSave(jsonValue.Message);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                ErrorWhileSave("");
            }
        });
    }

function ReturnFunction(data) {
   alert(data.data.Table1[0].BillId);
}

ApiCallFunction(Datatext, "Bill_master", ReturnFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ReturnFunction, i think data is undefined, maybe this should work instead :

```
function ReturnFunction(ReturnValue) {
  alert(ReturnValue.data.Table1[0].BillId);
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help,!! I have already tried this and alert is not working

Comment: What is the output of console.log(ReturnValue)?